# Getting data from Prisma directly in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, prisma, sveltekit

So I'm trying to get data directly into SvelteKit from Prisma without using a API.
I know that's not the way you would usually do it, and i've done it "normal" bevor, but I wanted to save some time this time.

What i have so far kind of works, but I have to reload the page for the data to be displayed the first time and it doesn't work when building and previewing it.
Is there a better way of doing it?

Here is my code:

```
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import {PrismaClient, type User} from '@prisma/client'

    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
        var allUsers: User[] = []
        const prisma = new PrismaClient()

        async function main() {
            allUsers = await prisma.user.findMany()
            console.log(allUsers)
        }

        main()
            .catch((e) => {
                throw e
            })
            .finally(async () => {
                await prisma.$disconnect()
            })
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each allUsers as user}
            <p>{user.email}</p>
    {/each}
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find solution? I don't think that's possible in sveltekit

Comment: @cikatomo Yes I found a solution but it was to complicated for me to understand and the author wrote that this is not a good way of doing it. I've already written an api now